# delete function in yii controller

Tags: php, yii

How do i get the delete button to work in Yii? These are my controller and view and i have a custom delete button.

```
public function actionDelete($id)

{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $model->DeletedItem = 1;

$model->save();

    echo"success";
    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));

}
```

and my view is:

```
function Delete(Iid,Itype){

    if(type=="a")
    {
        console.log("Assignment");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //data: Iid,
            url:  '/grade/delete/' + Iid,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //$.fn.yiiGridView.update('Assignment-grid');
            }
    });
```

Comment: You are using yii1  or yii2

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in yii1 for delete you should do this way (using $model->delete();)

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
  $model = $this->loadModel($id);
  //$model->DeletedItem = 1;
  $model->delete();
  // $model->save();

 echo"success";
 if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
 $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));

}
```

For the view custom delete botton  could be a path problem
try assign the routed path this way

```
 url:  <?php echo "'" .  Url::to(['grade/delete/']) ."'" ?>  + Iid,
```

Comment: this is a action delete for custom delete button. I have a jquery for the delete button in my view (that is above) and i am trying to create a actionDelete for that button but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: If dont' work the url call try with the url in the  answer .. i have update    ..